# Why is dry-struct initialization slow?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance, dry-rb

I have a Rails application that stores its configuration in 34 MySQL tables consisting of various objects and associations, for a total of about 900 records altogether. Up to recently the business logic was built on ActiveRecord, but performance was choppy because I didn't have enough control on how many queries were fired. Recently I "ported" the business logic to `Dry::Struct`, duplicating all the involved ActiveRecord classes to `Dry::Struct` value models and preloading all the configuration objects inside a `Configuration` instance: this drastically reduced the number of queries to a small and fixed amount, and improved performance by a noticeable margin because all the association “walking” is done in memory, and there's a lot of that.

So far so good, but the loading of the 34 tables, most of which I need at every request, still took 34 queries and about 160 ms. The strategy was going low level on ActiveRecord, loading all the records in all the tables as plain hashes, and then initializing the structs with those and storing everything in the `Configuration` object.

I wanted to improve performance further, so I had the idea of getting all the data in just one query, by making a `UNION` of all the fields in all the tables. That makes up a beefy 30-kilobyte SQL query, which is surprisingly executed in just 20 ms. Excellent! Now I just have to unroll this big structure in ~10 ms and I'm a winner!

Well, no. It turns out that just scanning the result array takes 48 ms (20 of which are the SQL query), that time grows up to 78 ms when parsing some JSON fields here and there and preparing the hashes to initialize the structs... and then initializing those takes an *additional* 89 ms all by itself. I wouldn't believe it if I hadn't measured every step by repeating the algorithm 100 times (after pre-warming memoized values, of course), but there it is. All in all, compared to the previous, much simpler algorithm of loading every table separately, there's no performance gain whatsoever although the single query is efficient.

Here is what the SQL looks like:

```sql
SELECT a1, a2, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM table_a
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, b1, b2, NULL, NULL FROM table_b
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, c1, c2 FROM table_c
```

which yields a “diagonal” structure like this

```sql
"string", 3, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL -- from table_a
"other string", 5, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL -- from table_a
NULL, NULL, 1, "{\"json\":true}", NULL, NULL -- from table_b
NULL, NULL, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL -- from table_b
NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 7, 10 -- from table_c
NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 9, 51 -- from table_c
```

then the following algorithm unfolds it into the original records:

```rb
  def preload_all!
    ranges = self.class.preload_field_ranges.invert
    logger.measure_debug("Preloaded configuration") do
      ApplicationRecord.connection.execute(self.class.preload_query).each do |data|
        # finding where the first significant column is
        pos = data.index { |i| !i.nil? }
        # resolving the table name based on where the significant value was found, exiting early
        range, table_name = ranges.select { |k, v| break [ k, v ] if pos.in?(k) }
        v_class = self.class.tables_to_value_classes[table_name]
        values = data[range].map do |i|
          case i
          when String
            # horrible kludge to parse JSON fields, because I wasn't able to inspect AR
            # classes to ask them which fields are serialized, any help is appreciated
            case
            when i[0].in?([ "{", "[" ]) then JSON.parse(i)
            else i
            end
          else i
          end
        end
        # assignments are for clarity, doing these operations inline shaves about 10 ms
        ivar = "@#{table_name}"
        hash = self.class.ar_attribute_names[table_name].zip(values).to_h
        v_model = v_class.new(hash.merge(configuration: self))
        vhash = instance_variable_get(ivar) || {}
        instance_variable_set(ivar, vhash.tap { |h| h[v_model.id] = v_model })
      end
    end
    self
  end
```

I tried to tighten the code as much as I could, but just removing the `v_class.new` part cuts the time in half. Is there any room for improvement?

As a side note, loading the `Marshal`ed finished `Configuration` object from Redis only takes 10 ms, but I wanted to avoid using Redis to prevent misalignments.

Comment: If you want help with MySQL, please show us the generated SQL.

Comment: @RickJames I added a snippet of similar SQL (the original one is gigantic), but the SQL doesn't seem to be the problem because the query is executed in barely 20 ms. Instead, I didn't expect that creating structs from hashes would take half of the total execution time. Of course, if there are better ways to load all the data from several tables in a single query, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Please show a short example of the incoming and outgoing data.  That UNION query is quite weird.

Comment: I added an example of what the return data looks like: it's really just all records from all tables next to one another. The real data is 200 columns (the sum of all the tables' columns) by 900 lines (the sum of all records in all tables), way too big to be posted here.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by none other than [solnic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/282051/solnic) himself:

> Change `.new` to `.load` and it'll just set the ivars w/o applying types, this will give you a massive speed boost. Do this only if you trust the data.